# Get Number of groups which have same frequency of digits in a given set of numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm

This is a question I had got in an interview and I was wondering what the best approach would be.
A list of numbers is given and we need to identify the number of groups in which the digits of each number have same frequency and print the groups. For example:
For example if numbers are:
1
10
3
33

There are 4 groups:

```
G1={1}has one 1. 
G2={3} has one 3. 
G3={10}has one 1 and one 0. 
G4={33}as two 3s.
```

I was thinking of keeping a vector of maps. The maps will contain a frequency of each digit. Now when a number comes check in the entire vector if there exists an entry which will have a same frequency map of the current number. If it exists append to a list. I am not able to identify how i should identify the groups as well to print it. Is there a better way to solve this problem as I feel my solution is really inefficient.

Comment: How much time you had in order to finish it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about how hash-table works. You apply a hash function to the item and based on this hash value you assign the item to a slot. But it may happen that two different items have the same hash value. In that case the hash-table will create a list of the values with the same hash. This is called a collision.

In a hash-table implementation we try to avoid collision. But here it will serve you well. If you can find a hash function such that: two numbers in the same group have the same hash value, you could easily group the numbers.

An example of such a hash function is this:

- convert the number to a string
- sort the string by ascending order

All numbers in the same group will have the same hash value.

Example implementation:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


unordered_map<string, vector<int>> group_numbers(vector<int> numbers) {
    unordered_map<string, vector<int>> results;
    for(auto n : numbers) {
        stringstream buffer;
        buffer << n;
        string hash;
        buffer >> hash;

        sort(begin(hash), end(hash));
        results[hash].push_back(n);
    }
    return results;
}


int main() {
    vector<int> numbers{1, 10, 3, 33, 133, 331, 313, 333};
    auto results = group_numbers(numbers);
    int group = 0;
    for(auto kv : results) {
        cout << "Group " << (++group) << " : ";
        copy(begin(kv.second), end(kv.second),
             ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Then when run it prints:

```
Group 1 : 333
Group 2 : 133 331 313
Group 3 : 1
Group 4 : 10
Group 5 : 33
Group 6 : 3
```

Comment: How much time it took you?

Comment: The idea: 3 minutes. The coding: 20 minutes. But it is a *classical* question. I didn't invent the solution, I read something similar there: [Programming Pearls](https://www.amazon.fr/Programming-Pearls-Jon-Bentley/dp/0201657880/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1461359148&sr=8-1&keywords=programming+pearls)

Comment: Nice I like it. Thanks for the resource

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood the question right, they didn't care about the actual numbers. They are just asking about the frequency. Therefore, this will provide us with a `std::map<int,int>` where `key` is the whole number from the list and `value` is the frequency of the numbers in that `key`. We only need to display categories as whatever has value of 1, 2, 3.. or maybe check which has equal `value` etc.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> MyVec = { 1, 10, 3, 33 }; // sample data
    std::map<int, int> MyMap;

    for (int i = 0; i < MyVec.size(); i++) // fill the map with ALL the numbers first
        MyMap[MyVec[i]]++;

    for (auto itr = MyMap.begin(); itr != MyMap.end(); itr++) // increment each value based on the frequence of the digits found in the key
    {
        if (itr->first < 10) // it has one
            continue;
        else
        {
            int temp = itr->first;
            while (temp >= 10)
            {
                temp = temp % 10;
                itr->second++;
            }
        }
    }

    for (auto itr = MyMap.begin(); itr != MyMap.end(); itr++) // display
    {
        std::cout << "first: " << itr->first << " second: " << itr->second << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: U have got the frequency right, I think i gave a bad example. Now if the list contains 133, 331,313. This should be grouped into one,  with 3 elements, as the frequency of 3 and 1 are same in all these 3 numbers

Comment: @user It's okay. I think interview questions are fun because they meant to be tricky and not direct. So 133 and 333 are not in the same group/category?

Comment: They should be in different category. As their frequency of each number is different.